# Correlation matrix for two Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

Say I have two dataframes:

```
df1   df2
A B    C D
1 3   -2 7
2 4    0 10
```

I need to create a correlation matrix which consists of columns from two dataframes.

```
corrmat_df
  C D
A 1 *  
B * 1
```

- stands for correlation

I can do it elementwise in nested loop, but maybe there is more pythonic way?
Thanks.

Comment: It suggests nested loop. I mentioned about it in my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply combine the dataframes and use `.corr()`:

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).corr()
#     A    B    C    D
#A  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
#B  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
#C  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
#D  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

The result contains all wanted (and also some unwanted) correlations. E.g.:

```
result[['C','D']].ix[['A','B']]
#     C    D
#A  1.0  1.0
#B  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: I need exactly C D columns and A B rows in a matrix as I'm gonna plot a heatmap. I don't need individual result. There ara dozens of columns in each dataframe and I don't know their names beforehand.

Comment: You are surely welcome to select whatever rows and columns you want: `result[['C','D']].ix[['A','B']]`.

Comment: This is simply a genius answer!